# Why are the actions button paginations not showing up properly at a VDataTable?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, v-data-table, vuetify-datatable

I'm working with Vue3, and Im (at least tyring to) implementing a data table with pagination using Vuetify.

Right now i just cant see why are the paginations (that left-right arrows for going back or forward between data pages) buttons not been rendered properly.
I mean, i can see they are at html, but their dimensions put them out of display, so i cannot use/test them.

I wonder if anyone can help me with this probably minor misunderstanding of mine, that would be nice.

here is my component right now

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    items-per-page-text="Linhas por página"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="statementStore.dataTableItems"
    class="elevation-1"
    item-value="valor"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useStatementStore } from "@/store/statement"

const statementStore = useStatementStore()
import { onBeforeMount } from 'vue';

onBeforeMount(async () => await statementStore.setEvents())

const itemsPerPage = ref(5); // Linhas por página (padrão 10);
const headers: any[] = [
  { title: 'Valor', align: 'start', sortable: false, key: 'valor', },
  { title: 'Descrição', key: 'descricao', align: 'end', },
  { title: 'Data', key: 'data', align: 'end', },
  { title: 'Método', key: 'metodo', align: 'end', },
  { title: 'Meio', key: 'meio', align: 'end', },
  { title: 'Fluxo', key: 'fluxo', align: 'end', },
];
</script>
```

rendering it at the vuetify playground (using mocked data), it shows all good. but on my app doesnt.

[the single that does nothing besides showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZX9N.png)